# HTTPS client in netty 4.0.0

Tags: netty

I'm having trouble making netty 4.0.0alpha6 HttpSnoopClient example to work with SSL. After enabling ssl in HttpSnoopClientInitializer (by uncommenting SslEngine initialization and adding SslHandler into pipeline) SSL handshake completes but no data/http request is sent by the client. Eventually client fails with

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine already closed
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:434)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.inboundBufferUpdated(SslHandler.java:819)
```

Server side is regular apache+mod_ssl. 
Is SslHandler supposed to work with Http* pipeline in 4.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I had a chance to test the `HttpSnoopClient` example today and found a bug in `SslHandler` which prevents the HTTP request from being sent.  I've just pushed the fix to master, and confirmed that the example retrieves data from https://www.google.com/ successfully.

However, I did not see such an exception even before I fix the `SslHandler`, so the problem you experienced might not be related with mine.  Please feel free to let me know if you still have the same problem with the master snapshot.